# Regex to Find And Replace Indic Characters

Tags: php, regex

I have a text file as follows

```
{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-२०१८/२०१८-.१-entry-list|caption=test event of २०१८}}{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-३१/३१-.१-entry-list|caption=test event of ३१}}{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-१८/१८-.१-entry-list|caption=test event of १८}}
```

I want to change all the instances of indic characters to their english equivalent only in the URL(s) and not the captions.

For Ex: २ becomes 2 and so on. I am trying to write an RegEx which will replaces all the instances between "/" of the URLs. Having no luck so far!.

My code is as follows

```
<?php
$pattern = "/\/([२]+)\//u";
$text=file_get_contents("Test.txt");
$text = preg_replace($pattern,'2',$text);
file_put_contents("MR-Test.txt",$text);
?>
```

Nothing seems to work so far!

Edit: The url(s) i am using are in a text file and  i have to replace only the indic text in URL and no where else..

Comment: Tried `$text = str_replace('२', '2', $text)` yet?

Comment: `$text = strtr( $text, array( '२' => '2' ) );` would also work and you can load in as many replacements into that array as you need.

Comment: the said text is in lot of URL in a text file.. i have to search between "/" i cannot replace anywhere else other than the url

Comment: @PrashantShirsat Okay, so why do you say that our suggestions fail?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - strtr is correct, but i have to search in a text file containing lot of URLs and i have to replace only in those URLs... sorry for not being clear!

Comment: You should provide a small sample of your text file and explain where you wish to replace and where you want to avoid replacements.

Comment: I just changed my post to be more clear :)

Comment: Is something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/j1N2SF/1/) what you're looking for? Note that could still run into false positives. One sample is just not enough to generate a robust pattern

Comment: Yeah! But how do i upvote your post! the solution is great! :)

Comment: `indic characters` How many are there ? And how do you know what to replace it with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job with preg_replace_callback, first find the right digits to replace then replace them in the callback:

```
$text = '{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-२०१८/२०१८-.१-entry-list|caption=test event of २०१८}}{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-३१/३१-.१-entry-list|caption=test event of ३१}}{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-१८/१८-.१-entry-list|caption=test event of १८}}';

$res = preg_replace_callback('/caption=.+?}}(*SKIP)(*F)|[०१२३४५६७८९]/u', 
                    function($m) {
                        return preg_replace(
                            array('/०/','/१/','/२/','/३/','/४/','/५/','/६/','/७/','/८/','/९/'), 
                            array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'), 
                            $m[0]);
                    }
                    , $text);
echo $res,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-2018/2018-.1-entry-list|caption=test event of २०१८}}{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-31/31-.1-entry-list|caption=test event of ३१}}{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-18/18-.1-entry-list|caption=test event of १८}}
```

**Explanation:**

```
caption=.+?}}       # matches caption until }}
(*SKIP)(*F)         # and skip that match
|                   # OR
[०१२३४५६७८९]          # 1 digit
```

Answer (score 1):

Our desired `२` comes first, which we collect, then we collect the undesired `२`s  using alternation:

```
(२)|(caption=(.+?)}})
```

finally, we would be replacing that with `2` and `$2`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ymqu1R/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/(२)|(caption=(.+?)}})/m';
$str = '{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-२०१८/२०१८-.१-entry-list|caption=test event of २०१८}}{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-३१/३१-.१-entry-list|caption=test event of ३१}}{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-१८/१८-.१-entry-list|caption=test event of १८}}';
$subst = '2$2';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### Output

```
{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-2०१८/2०१८-.१-entry-list|2caption=test event of २०१८}}{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-३१/३१-.१-entry-list|2caption=test event of ३१}}{{https://www.test.com/events/test-event-१८/१८-.१-entry-list|2caption=test event of १८}}
```

Comment: Thank you! but i dont want to change in the CAPTION.. only the URL!

Comment: the content becomes "/test-event०१८०१८-.१-entry-list" where as the intended was "/test-event-2०१८/2०१८-.१-entry-list" !